# Common Cathode vs. Common Anode (RGB LED)

Tags: led, rgb, power-consumption

What is the difference in power consumption between these two RGB LED circuits, one common cathode, the other common andode?

[image]

Comment: How could there be any difference? Please explain.

Comment: Where did the statement come from? There may be some context behind it. Assuming the same supply voltage, same base LED devices and the same resistors, the power will be the same.

Comment: Haven't you already asked the question? The schematics are unnecessary. Better would be to tell us *where* you have heard that. Because as it is, it is *wrong*, but maybe there was some particular context in which it was right, but we can't know.

Comment: With your schematics the answer is, obviously, not. But if the circuit is arranged like in [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/242029/104387) maybe the power dissipated on resistor is different because there isn't the resistor!

Comment: The first result when searching: https://vision-pi.net/common-cathode-vs-common-anode-led/, seems to suggest you can use less power with the common cathode circuit, E.g. by varying the supply voltage for individual RGB channels.

Answer (score 2):

*Is it right?* **No it is not**

It is utter nonsense stated by someone who obviously knows nothing about LEDs and/or electronics.

From the LED's point of view, they don't even "know" how they're connected.

Maybe the person who made the statement compared a 20 years old common cathode to a brand new common anode. Sure in 20 years LED efficiency has improved but that is unrelated to the way the LEDs are connected.

Comment: Thank's for reply. Then, in captured image, how to calculate power consumption?

Comment: Power is voltage x current so measure both and calculate.