# I don't understand the text about LED's type and power consumption

Tags: led, power, power-consumption, common-emitter

On my web-surfing, I found some information about LED's type and power consumption.

I don't understand below (Red-lines.)

Why 'common cathode' power consumption is lower than 'common anode'?

Please explain exactly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In short: It can be more power efficient to employ dedicated, optimized power supplies for different LED types than to use a single power supply and 'burn' excess energy in resistors.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

*Figure 1. LED current vs forward voltage curves. Note that red has much lower \$ V_F \$ than green and blue.*

Red LEDs have a lower forward voltage than green and blue. If connected directly to the same supply as the green and blue they would draw a very high current and would be destroyed. To prevent this we normally add series resistance. On a matrix display this would require one resistor per LED and, as they point out, would increase PCB size.

The problem could be solved by sinking the current into a dedicated negative rail of, say, +0.5 to +1V, for the red LEDs. This would be an unusual topology however and a simpler solution is to feed all the reds from a lower voltage supply with common negative rail switching for all three LEDs. This solution also has the advantage of high efficiency.

The additional Vdd supply would be very easy to incorporate into a custom switched mode power supply with the addition of another transformer winding or tap, rectifier and smoothing capacitor. The common negative switching of the common cathode LED is much easier to implement than the high-side switching of the common anode LED.

Comment: I like how the green line has multiple amps for the same voltage

Comment: Must be a tunnel LED :P

Comment: I noticed that but the LED I/V illustration was still good value for the money. ;^)

Answer (score 6):

This isn't so much about LED's, as it is about using them to make a display panel.  Each triad of red, green, and blue make up a colored pixel. When all 3 are illuminated, the pixel will be white so long as all 3 are the same brightness.  Red LED's have a lower forward voltage drop--this is due to physics and the chemistry used to make them.  So, as the voltage increases, the red turns on first.  With the three LED's in parallel, the red will take most of the current and be far brighter than the other two.

To remedy this, you must either operate the red LED at a lower voltage (and thus use a separate power supply), or else create an extra voltage drop in series (thus, a resistor).

The common cathode arrangement naturally lends itself to using a different power supply for each color.  The common anode doesn't, although technically you could still do it if you were willing to create "different voltage grounds" (or more correctly, different voltage returns) for each color.  Most reasonable people would avoid designing something like that, so it really comes down to the two examples shown in the data sheet.